# If-equals statement in makefile as a one-liner

Tags: bash, makefile

The following works as intended:

```
branch := $(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

ifeq ($(branch), master)
    ami_regions = us-west-2
endif

show_regions:
    echo $(ami_regions)
```

How could this `ifeq` statement be written as a one-liner, where the variable is set if the condition passes, otherwise sets the variable as another value or simply leaves it unset?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That should be possible. Try from [chapter 8.4](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditional-Functions) one conditional in combination with string search from [chapter 8.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions) of the manual:

```
branch := $(shell git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

ami_regions = $(if $(findstring master,$(branch)),us-west-2,)

show_regions:
    echo $(ami_regions)
```

The function `$if` will return the value from the then branch if `$findstring` returns anything. `$findstring` will return `master` if `$(branch)` contains the string `master`. The downside is that this will also match something like `master-tests`.

To make this match exactly master you will have to rely on bash: `$(shell if [ master = $(branch) ]; then echo "true"; fi )`. But then you also have to take care that `$(branch)` does not contain shell code with side effects (usually not).

### Update

Renaud Pacalet and MadScientist in the comments have given improvements to the use of `$findstring`: Use `$filter` or `$patsubst`. As the string you are searching isn't a pattern, using simple `$subst` instead of `$patsubst` is also possible.

```
$(if $(patsubst master,,$(branch)),,us-west-2)
```

Notice that `us-west-2` moved to the else branch, as `$patsubst/subst` replace the found string with the empty string leading to a false condition if the substitution is successful.

```
$(if $(filter master,$(branch)),us-west-2,)
```

`$filter` returns words from the input that match the supplied patter. Because the pattern is a single word, in this case it only returns exact matches.

So basically both alternatives give similar results. Differences arise if  `$branch` contains spaces: Spaces between removed words will be returned by `$patsubst`, while `$filter` only returns matches. Git doesn't allow branches with spaces, this case should not occur.

Comment: To match exactly you can use `$(if $(patsubst master,,$(branch)),,us-west-2)`.

Comment: hm, so basically using the else branch in case patsubst completely eats the text in `$(branch)`. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Better is to use `$(if $(filter master,$(branch)),us-west-2,)`

Comment: @MadScientist: in this particular case you are probably right. But in the general case `filter` operates on words, not on a single string. So if `banch = "master master"`, for instance, `filter` would match but `patsubst` would not...

Comment: As far as I understand the manual, patsubst also operates on words. But it returns the spaces between the words (in my test with strings like "master master master") which will guide the conditional into the then branch. But thanks to both of you for input, I learned a bit more about make.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it all in your `$(shell ...)` expression:

```
region := $(shell test `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` = master && echo us-west-2)

all:
  echo $(region)
```

Comment: Understood, but I'm wondering how it would/could be done via Make

Answer (score 0):

A general one-liner if

`$(if $(strip $(subst $(a),,$(b))),false-command,true-command)`

For your case you can do this:

`$(if $(strip $(subst $(branch),,master)),,$(eval ami_regions = us-west-2))`